# Anyone knows something like RSPec for PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, testing, rspec, phpunit

RSPec is a great ruby test framework (for test driven development),
anyone knows something like rspec but, for PHP?

Comment: [Kahlan](https://github.com/kahlan/kahlan) is a closer existing implementation (note: I'm its creator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de) is the de-facto standard for UnitTesting in PHP.
It can do [BD Testing](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/behaviour-driven-development.html) to a limited extent:

> The PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase class adds a story framework that faciliates the definition of a Domain-Specific Language for Behaviour-Driven Development. Inside a scenario, given(), when(), and then() each represent a step. and() is the same kind as the previous step. The following methods are declared abstract in PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase and need to be implemented:
>
> ```
> runGiven(&$world, $action, $arguments)
> ...
>
> runWhen(&$world, $action, $arguments)
> ...
>
> runThen(&$world, $action, $arguments)
> ...
> ```

Edit: [An more sophisticated alternative might be Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389601/cucumber-for-php-application) with [Behat](http://behat.org/)

Answer (score 16):

[PHPSpec](http://phpspec.net/) is a Behaviour-Driven Development framework for php. I've not used it myself yet, though, so I can't comment on it specifically.

Comment: This link works: http://www.phpspec.net/

Answer (score 5):

Behat!  Built on top of Symfony 2 components.  Syntactically, not as nice as Ruby implementation but still get the benefits of BDD.

I just stumbled upon it myself and haven't used it yet.  From a glance, it looks like it's using closures (which it would need to do to work like RSpec/Cucumber) which is a PHP 5.3 addition.

http://behat.org/

Comment: Behat is a PHP clone of Cucumber, not RSpec. This tool is for behaviour testing at the integration level (aka. acceptance testing), not really unit testing like RSpec.

Answer (score 2):

There are few of RSpec clones in PHP.

[PHPSpec](http://www.phpspec.net/)
[Spectrum](https://github.com/mkharitonov/spectrum/)

Also there is an original testing framework [Codeception](http://codeception.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only intrested in the output of tests, you could use [phpunit-progress](https://github.com/Maher4Ever/phpunit-progress) which makes your tests results look exactly like RSpecs' results.

Answer (score -2):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is another one worth to mention here.

Comment: Selenium is for automating browsers. While you might *use* this when writing various tests, it is not a testing framework as the question is asking.